# twitter bootstrap collapse not opening once its closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I Have a image slider with the twitter bootstrap collapse function in it, The slider lets you know when it slide has changed like this.

```
  si.ev.on('rsBeforeAnimStart', function(){

    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');

  });
```

Twitter Bootstrap collapse closes on this condition but does not open again if I try to open it by clicking the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn noDrag" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_1">
 <h4 class="dropdown-toggle">Open Drop down</h4>
</button>   

<div id="collapse_1" class="gda_block collapse out"> .. content </div>
```

Comment: It could be a CSS transition event issue. Easy test: Does it work in IE?

Comment: thats most likely it, it breaks on FireFox too...once the slider moves that button's click function doesn't do anything.

Comment: In a different case, but similar behavior, it was that someone had left off the relevant CSS which contains the transitions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13038454/570918  However, yours sounds more likely a JS issue. Can you set up a JSFiddle or Plnkr to demo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap collapse only toggles once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202285/bootstrap-collapse-only-toggles-once)