# bootstrap collapse only toggles once

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm once again pulling my hair out here... so I've got bootstrap collapse working with jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/rasreye/xtPtH/1/) -- but when I add to my site, it only collapses once... (i.e. click on a heading it opens, click again it closes, click again and NOTHING)

Here's a link to the actual page with the issue: http://www.urbanoffering.com/custom-optimizations

Heres the JS

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {

    $('.accordion').on('show', function (e) {
         $(e.target).prev('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle').addClass('active');
    });

    $('.accordion').on('hide', function (e) {
        $(this).find('.accordion-toggle').not($(e.target)).removeClass('active');
    });

});
});//]]>  

</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  location.hash && $(location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
});
</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                 <h2>Shirt Collars</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                <ul>
                <li class="coprod"><img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/standard.jpg" alt="Standard Collar" width="225" height="225" />
                    <h3>Standard</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"><img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/standard_buttons_1.jpg" alt="Standard with Button Collar" width="225" height="225" />
                    <h3>Standard with Buttons</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"><img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/small_standard.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                    <h3>Small Standard</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"><img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/small_standard_buttons.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                    <h3>Small Standard with Buttons</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"><img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/standard_round.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                    <h3>Standard Round</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"><img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/cutaway.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                    <h3>Cutaway</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"><img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/cutaway_round.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                    <h3>Cutaway Round</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"><img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/standard_double_buttons.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                    <h3>Standard with Double Buttons</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"><img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/Barrel.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                    <h3>Barrel</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"><img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/tuxedo.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="225" />
                    <h3>Tuxedo</h3>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                  <h2>Shirt Cuffs</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                 <ul>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/single_round.jpg" alt="Single Round" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>Single Round</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/single_notch.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>Single Notch</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/single_edge.jpg" alt="Single Edge" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>Single Edge</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/double_round.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>Double Round</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/double_notch.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>Double Notch</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/double_edge.jpg" alt="Double Edge" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>Double Edge</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/french_round.jpg" alt="Red Ribbon Lapel Flower" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>French Round</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/french_notch.jpg" alt="French Notch" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>French Notch</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/french_edge.jpg" alt="French Edge" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>French Edge</h3>
                </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
                  <h2>Shirt Pleats</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                <ul>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/double_wide.jpg" alt="Double Wide" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>Double Wide</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/double_middle.jpg" alt="Double Dibble" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>Double Middle</h3>
                </li>
                <li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/darts.jpg" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
                <h3>Darts</h3>
                </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour">
                  <h2>Suit Buttons</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                  <ul>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/suit_buttons.png" alt="Double Wide" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>One Button</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/suit_buttons_two.png" alt="Double Dibble" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Two Button</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/suit_buttons_three.png" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Three Button</h3>
</li>
</ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFive">
                  <h2>Suit Lapels</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseFive" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                  <ul>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/standard_notch.png" alt="Double Wide" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Standard Notch</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/narrow_notch.png" alt="Double Dibble" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Narrow Notch</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/peak_lapel.png" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Peak Lapel</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/shawl_lapel.png" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Shawl Lapel</h3>
</li>
</ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSix">
                  <h2>Suit Details</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseSix" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                  <ul>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/pick_stitching.png" alt="Double Wide" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Pick Stitching</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/functional_lapel.png" alt="Double Dibble" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Functional Lapel</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/functional_sleeve.png" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Functional Sleeve Button Holes</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/pen_pockets.png" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Pen Pocket</h3>
</li>
</ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSeven">
                  <h2>Suit Pockets</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseSeven" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                  <ul>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/regular_pockets.png" alt="Double Wide" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Regular Pockets</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/slanted_pockets.png" alt="Double Dibble" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Slanted Pockets</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/regular_ticket_pocket.png" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Regular Pockets with Ticket Pocket</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/slanted_ticket_pockets.png" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Slanted Pockets with Ticket Pocket</h3>
</li>
</ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseEight">
                  <h2>Suit Vents</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseEight" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                 <ul>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/no_vents.png" alt="Double Wide" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>No Vents</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/one_vent.png" alt="Double Dibble" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>One Vent</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/two_vents.png" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Two Vents</h3>
</li>
</ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordion-group">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseNine">
                  <h2>Suit Pant Pleats</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseNine" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                  <ul>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/no_pant_pleat.png" alt="Double Wide" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>No Pant Pleats</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/one_pant_pleat.png" alt="Double Dibble" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Single Pant Pleats</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/double_pant_pleat.png" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>Double Pant Pleats</h3>
</li>
<li class="coprod"> <img src="http://www.urbanoffering.com/media/wysiwyg/pant_pleat_cuffs.png" alt="Darts" width="225" height="225" />
<h3>With Cuffs</h3>
</li>
</ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Does your project use prototypeJS by chance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I experienced this very problem awhile back.  It was caused by a conflict created by the old prototypeJS library.  Our fix was to go into the bootstrap file, find the Collapse section, find the transition method therein, and change

```
this.$element.trigger(startEvent)
```

to

```
this.$element.triggerHandler(startEvent)
```

And of course the downside is that you'll have to remember to add this code in every time you upgrade bootstrap to a newer version.

Comment: Thanks so much! I replaced the corresponding lines from 'Bootstrap: collapse.js v3.1.1' in the bootstrap.js. Then magic happened!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem it was caused by double including of javascript files.

I did **include my library javascript files twice**, when I removed the repeated ones, it is working well.

Answer (score 1):

I was having an issue with bxslider js conflict and in the bootstrap js file I replaces all the $element.trigger with $element.triggerHandler and it worked.

Comment: I had a minimized version, so I also replaced all. Worked!

Answer (score 1):

I was having an identical issue with Bootstrap 3.3.1 and Prototype 1.7 in a Magento build...

A find a replace on **$element.trigger** with **$element.triggerHandler** in the Bootstrap library worked like a charm.

Be sure to back up your Bootstrap library before trying this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. My fix was simply updating bootstrap and jQuery to their latest release.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using this jquery-ui effect, which highlight an anchor target for a few seconds :

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function () {
    var target = this.hash;
    $(target).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

I've put something more specific as a selector:

```
$('a[href^="#somethingSpecific"]')
```

and things got back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and it got resolved when I updated bootstrap css and js files. I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

I upgraded the theme's old bootstrap, all is good now.